# How to run Gryffin security tool?

Tags: security, testing

Yahoo has been launched the Gryffin security check tool. [https://github.com/yahoo/gryffin][1] this URL given the details of tool.
I have done installation of all prerequisites of Gryffin but not getting how to run the tool.
          Please Help.

Comment: Dead link. Please provide some more information about your situation and the proper link.

Comment: https://github.com/yahoo/gryffin

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Under the RUN tab it shows WIP (work in progress). What would be the guidelines in Run tab if I want to run the Gryffin? And want to know one more thing, Is it possible to set up all those prerequisites and gryffin on windows OS? Because I am not able to do so. Some prerequisites are not compatible to windows OS.

Answer (score 0):

**Pre-requisites**

```
Go
PhantomJS, v2
Sqlmap (for fuzzing SQLi)
Arachni (for fuzzing XSS and web vulnerabilities)
NSQ ,
    running lookupd at port 4160,4161
    running nsqd at port 4150,4151
    with --max-msg-size=5000000
Kibana and Elastic search, for dashboarding
    listening to JSON over port 5000
    Preconfigured docker image available in https://hub.docker.com/r/yukinying/elk/
```

**Installation**

```
go get -u github.com/yahoo/gryffin/...
```

**Run**

(WIP)

Comment: Thanks Ravi, I would like to know more about things/steps come under Run. Because it shows work in progress.

Comment: I have run Gryffin successfully. Now the challenge is how to create session of application through Gryffin and access the sub URL's for scanning.